# Accesing struct value, changes struct value

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I was trying to understand how pointers work in c when i came across this weird problem.

Now, I wanted to build a linked list. The first thing I did was adding the add function. Once the function add a node to the last node of the list(which it does successfully)

```
typedef struct linkedLists{
    int x;
    struct linkedLists *next;
    //int (*add)(int) = add;
}linkedList;

void addF(linkedList *l, int y){
    linkedList adder = {.x=y};
    l->next = &adder;
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    linkedList list = {.x=2,.next=NULL};
    printf("%d\n",list.x);

    addF(&list,3);

    printf("%d\n",list.x);
    // If you comment this line the result changes to what it's  
    //expected

    printf("%d\n",(*list.next).x);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If I run

```
printf("%d\n",(*list.next).x);
```

I get 3, which is desired. However, if I run

```
printf("%d\n",list.x);
printf("%d\n",(*list.next).x);
```

I get: 
2
Random number

Comment: `l->next = &adder;` overwrites the `->next` node each time with the same `linkedList adder` node which is declared local to `addF()` and ceases to exist when `addF()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function

```
void addF(linkedList *l, int y){
    linkedList adder = {.x=y};
    l->next = &adder;
    return;
}
```

You leak a pointer (&adder) to an object, which lifetime ends at return of the function. You have to either use the `static` keyword

```
static linkedList adder = {.x=y};
```

or allocate space dynamically with `malloc()` & co.

Howeber, `list.x` should always evaluate to `2` in both cases.

Comment: How would making it `static` help. There will only be one `static linkedList adder = {.x=y};` so future additions would overwrite `l->next` each time `addF()` is called. Your 2nd option would be fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `addF()` is only called once, so in the case of the program shown, it would help. If it is called more than once, then this option isn't viable of course.

Comment: Yes, you are correct there. In the case the list is limited to a 2-node list, `static` will work for the 2nd node.

Answer (score 1):

`l->next` is assigned a pointer value that will soon become invalid once `addF()` ends.  Result: *Undefined behavior*.

```
void addF(linkedList *l, int y){
    linkedList adder = {.x=y};  // adder is local
    l->next = &adder;  
    return;
}
```

What makes more sense is to walk the linked list (assuming it has at least one node) and append a new node.

```
void addF_alt(linkedList *l, int y) {
  while (l->next) {
    l = l->next;
  }
  l->next = malloc(sizeof *(l->next));
  if (l->next) {
    l = l->next;
    l->next = NULL;
    l->x = y;
  }
}
```

---

What is more common is to do *all* node appending via a function.

```
TBD code
```

Comment: That makes 3 answers in 15 seconds all pointing out the same issue -- here's to consistency `:)`

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful!